# Sed command to reverse print a file skips last line

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to use `sed` to reverse print a file (I know it can be done in myriads of other ways, like `tac`, for example). This is what I got so far:

```
sed -n -r '/.+/{x;H;$p}' nums
```

The file `nums` contains a number on each line, from 1 to 25. The logic is this, each number is first copied to the `holdspace`, while the contents of the `holdspace` are copied to `patspace` through `x;`. So now `holdspace` contains the current number, while `patspace` contains the numbers till now in reverse order. Then `H;` appends the list of numbers gone through until now to the `holdspace`, so that the latest numbr always stays on top. Finally, when last line is reached, it is done for one last time, and printed out through `$p`.

However, the command outputs only the numbers 24 to 1 in reverse order. The first line should be 25, but somehow that line is being skipped.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing one last `x`.  You swap the contents of the last line into the hold space, but you never pull it back out before printing.

```
sed -n -r -e '/.+/{x;H}' -e '${x;p}'
```

You also get an extra blank line because you really don't want to do the 'H' on the first line, since that preserves the initial blank contents of the hold space.  I would do this:

```
sed -n -r -e '/.+/x' -e '2,$H' -e '${x;p}' nums
```

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I just observed your first point. However, when I tried this: `sed -n -r '/.+/{x;H;x;$p}' nums`, it prints only 25. Why?

Comment: Oh, I get it, the final swap has to be done only on the last line, mine does it on every line, right?

Comment: You don't want to do two `x`s on each line, only on the last one.  Doing two on every line is a no-op.

Comment: Yep, yep, got that. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkReed +1 for the explanation. Though idiomatically you would want to delete the pattern space after first swap like `sed -nr '/.+/{x;1d;H};${x;p}' nums` and `/.+/` is only needed if there are blank lines, if there are no blank lines it can be reduced to `sed -n '{x;1d;H};${x;p}' nums`

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` should do:

```
sed '1!G;h;$!d' file
```

ot this:

```
sed -n '1!G;h;$p' file
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this solution. I just want to know why mine isn't working.